# APPLE NEWS API POST Request

Tags: python, python-requests, apple-news

I am trying to post articles using apple news API tried using the Postman following all the steps provided by documentation, as well executed the python code provided in apple documentation.

```
    POSThttps://news-api.apple.com/channels/channelID/articles2018-02-06T05:15:53Zmultipart/form-data; 
Authorization headers authorization = {str} 'HHMAC; key=ID; signature=ID; date=2018-02-07T05:15:53Z'
```

got: error stating Wrong singature

Python

```
import requests
import base64
from hashlib import sha256
import hmac
from datetime import datetime
import glob
import argparse
import os
import mimetypes
from requests.packages.urllib3.filepost import encode_multipart_formdata
from requests.packages.urllib3.fields import RequestField

arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Publish an article using the Apple News API')
arg_parser.add_argument('article_directory', metavar='ARTICLE_DIR', type=str, help='A directory containing an article.JSON file and resources')
args = arg_parser.parse_args()

channel_id = '[YOUR CHANNEL-ID]'
api_key_id = '[YOUR API-KEY]'
api_key_secret = '[YOUR API KEY-SECRET]'
method = 'POST'
url = 'https://news-api.apple.com/channels/%s/articles' % channel_id
session = requests.Session()
session.verify = False

def part(filename):
    name = os.path.basename(filename)
    with open(filename) as f:
        data = f.read()
    part = RequestField(name, data)
    part.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'form-data; filename="%s"; size=%d'  % (name, os.stat(filename).st_size)
    part.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/JSON' if name.endswith('.JSON') else 'application/octet-stream'
    return part

def send_signed_request(method, url, filenames):
    body, content_type = encode_multipart_formdata([part(f) for f in filenames])
    req = requests.Request(method, url, data=body, headers={'Content-Type': content_type})
    req = req.prepare()
    date = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
    canonical_request = method + url + str(date) + content_type + body
    key = base64.b64decode(api_key_secret)
    hashed = hmac.new(key, canonical_request, sha256)
    signature = hashed.digest().encode('base64').rstrip('/n')
    authorization = 'HHMAC; key=%s; signature=%s; date=%s' % (api_key_id, str(signature), date)
    req.headers['Authorization'] = authorization
    return session.send(req)


response = send_signed_request(method, url, glob.glob('%s/*' % args.article_directory))

print response.status_code
print response.text
```

> error: {"errors":[{"code":"MISSING","keyPath":["article.json"]}]}

I also converted the python code to java and executed seeing the same error but able to read articles.

Question:
Any suggestions on what is going wrong or In order to create articles does apple account be approved by Apple etc. Any information would be helpfull.

Comment: Did you intentionally leave out values for `channel_id`, `api_key_id` and `api_key_secret`? Because if you use the script above as you posted it, it won't work because you can not authenticate. This would also fit the error message you got: `Wrong signature`.

Comment: Yes, intentionally left out the values.

Answer (score 0):

This script requires a folder path as an argument. This folder has to have the following structure:

```
--- folder
 |---- article.json
 |---- image.jpg
```

Image files are optional if your article.json file requires them.

When the python file is executed, it should be executed like this :

```
python script_name.py 'folder/'
```